# Nodejs Axios Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: (URL). is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.sa-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"

Tags: node.js, axios, proxy, request, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to request an API from a third party server from a shared hosting server, so i don't have root access, and receive this error, but when i try it from my insomnia, it works normally, aparently its something due to proxy or certificates. Already tried using `httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })` in axios request options, and tried  `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`, but no success. I didn't paste cert and server info info but if it's necessary i can share it. That's how i'm making the request:

```html
async appInfo(){
    
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `${this.url}/api/v2/me/shipment/app-settings`,
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Authorization':`Bearer ${this.bearer}`, 
        'User-Agent': this.user_agent
      }
    };
    
    var response = await axios(config)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

i don't know if you fixed it already, but i will answer anyways. It might help others. Here's the solution i found here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1650

Seeing your code, you should have the agent config outside of the header. Like that:

```
// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Warning: It may be a security failure, only use it if you really trust where you sharing the data.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi! haven't really fixed it, but had some other ways "not too right" ways to solve it, i'll try your answer today and bring back what I get.